# JSoup Throws IO Exception: Too many redirects occurred trying to load URL

Tags: java, http, exception, post, jsoup

I am trying to make a username migrater for minecraft.net as a mod so people will be able to migrate their account ingame to discourage cracking of accounts. In order to do that I need to post a form to the website. I manage to successfully obtain the cookies so that the authenticityToken will remain the same but whenever I try to post the data back to the site it throws 'java.io.IOException: Too many redirects occurred trying to load URL https://account.mojang.com/migrate'

I am really not sure why this is happening but it may be to do with the website. The authentityToken definitely matches. I have checked this when not posting to the site and supplying the same cookies. Here is the code I am currently using

```
try {
        Response response = Jsoup.connect("https://account.mojang.com/migrate").execute(); //downloads site to get the cookies
        String auth = response.body();
        String auth2 = auth.split("name=\"authenticityToken\" value=\"")[1];
        auth = auth2.split("\">")[0];
        Map<String, String> cookies = response.cookies();
        Connection connection = Jsoup.connect("https://account.mojang.com/migrate").data("action", "/migrate/check")
                .data("authenticityToken", auth)
                .data("mcusername", "username")
                .data("password", "password")
                .method(Method.POST)
                .followRedirects(true);
        for (Entry<String, String> cookie : cookies.entrySet()) {
            connection.cookie(cookie.getKey(), cookie.getValue());
        }
        connection.execute(); //exception thrown here
        Document document = connection.get();
        String docHtml = document.html();
        System.out.println(docHtml);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any help at all would be appreciated greatly

Answer (score 1):

```
final Response response = 
    Jsoup.connect("https://account.mojang.com/migrate").execute();
// parse the response as a document, so that we can extract stuff
final Document doc = response.parse();
// correct way to extract parsed html
final Element authToken = doc.select("input[name^=authenticityToken]").get(0);
final Map<String, String> cookies = response.cookies();
// action isn't part of the querystring. The form POST URL is our target.
final Connection connection = 
        Jsoup.connect("https://account.mojang.com/migrate/check")
            .data("authenticityToken", authToken.val()) // correct way to extract val
            .data("mcusername", "username")
            .data("password", "password")
            .method(Method.POST)
            .followRedirects(true);
for (final Entry<String, String> cookie : cookies.entrySet()) {
    connection.cookie(cookie.getKey(), cookie.getValue());
}
final Response postResponse = connection.execute(); // consume response
System.out.println(postResponse.body());
```

Response JSON:

```
{"error":"Invalid username or password."}
```

Your Mistakes:

1. The form action is not a query string parameter. Thus `.data("action", "/migrate/check")` is incorrect. The form action is part of the POST URL as shown in my code above.
2. `Document document = connection.get();` is making a GET request at the URL. This is incorrect. `connection.execute()` has already made a POST. Just read the response, `final Response postResponse = connection.execute()`.
3. There's no need to parse the hidden input, authenticityToken like that. Jsoup can do it for you as I have demonstrated.

Comment: Thankyou for the help but there is one more problem. That problem is that the webbrowser then links to https://account.mojang.com/migrate/chooseEmail which returns a 404 error for me? Not sure how the webbrowser gets there and that is the page with the choice to migrate the account on

Answer (score 0):

`HttpConnection.Responce` have  `MAX_REDIRECTS` constant that equals 20.
Your execution exceeded this limit, so IOException was thrown.

Seems that connection stuck in endless loop of redirects. Try to change the method of posting data.

**EDIT**
Yeap, every new page after redirect have 302 status code. So it the problem is with your request maybe.

Comment: Strange, I haven't encountered any redirect loop. His request was incorrect, but 'twas just 404ing for me.